# How to slove Loading chunk failed issue on Xampp Server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm developing a project where I used Laravel 8 and vue 2. Everything works perfectly when I'm serving my application using **localhost/my-project** then everything loads correctly but my chunks which is generated from webpack is doesn't loading. And at the end of the result it'll redirect me to **localhost** url directly. How can I solve this problem. Here's my webpack configuration file's

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");


let css_plugin = 'public/frontend/css/';
let js_plugin = 'public/frontend/js/';
mix.setResourceRoot(process.env.MIX_ASSET_URL);
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/frontend/js')
    .vue().combine([
    css_plugin + 'bootstrap.min.css',
    css_plugin + 'materialdesignicons.min.css',
    css_plugin + 'animate.min.css',
    css_plugin + 'structure.css',
    css_plugin + 'main.css',
    css_plugin + 'responsive.css',
    css_plugin + 'custom.css',
    css_plugin + 'development.css',
    css_plugin + 'vue-tel-input.css',
    css_plugin + 'vue-toastr-2.min.css',
    css_plugin + 'vue-plyr.css',
], 'public/frontend/css/app.css').combine([
    js_plugin + 'html5shiv.min.js',
    js_plugin + 'respond.min.js',
], 'public/frontend/js/plugin.js').webpackConfig({
    output: {
        // filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'frontend/js/frontendChunks/[name].js',
        publicPath: '/public/',
    },
    plugins: [
        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),      // load this package to see which plugins with its size detail
        new CompressionPlugin({             // very import to compress the assets
            filename: "[path][base].gz",
            algorithm: "gzip",
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.svg$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    ]
});


if (mix.inProduction()) {                       // In production environtment use versioning
    mix.version();
}
// mix.extract();
/*module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    optimization: {
        nodeEnv: 'production',
        minimize: true
    }
};*/
```

**.env**

```
MIX_ASSET_URL="/public"
```

config/app.php

```
'mix_url' => env('MIX_ASSET_URL', null),
```

And here is the error I' am getting
[image]

Here you can see that my chunk loading url is **http://localhost/public/frontend/js/frontendChunks/980.js** but it should be **http://localhost/my-project/public/frontend/js/frontendChunks/980.js**.

Please help me to how can I solve this problem

Comment: For your case, try changing `publicPath: '/public/'` to `publicPath: 'public/'`

Comment: ok let my try this

Comment: @kenLee your solution works but when I'm navigating to any router-link it will redirect me to http://localhost/products this url which should be http://localhost/my-project/products

Comment: all of the links have same behavior like I'm defining the below routes using router link
<router-link :to="{ name : 'daily.deals' }"><span class=""><img
                                v-lazy="defaultAssets.pencil_image" alt="Image"
                                class="img-fluid">{{lang.daily_deals}}</span></router-link>
and in route.js like below
 {
                path: '/daily-deals',
                name: 'daily.deals',
                component: dailyDeals,
                meta: {
                    title: 'Daily Deals'
                }
            },

Comment: I am still having the same issue..can you check if my constructor is ok or not??
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    history: true,
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        return {x: 0, y: 0}
    }
});

Comment: and route for daily deals 
{
                path: './daily-deals',
                name: 'daily.deals',
                component: dailyDeals,
                meta: {
                    title: 'Daily Deals'
                }
            },

Comment: I am suspecting that you should change the Router base from "/" to "/my-project/" for your case

Comment: but what if need to deploy in multiple domain. Then I need to change manually for every domain

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: no this is not working....I used a location.pathname in base URL. Its working fine but when I am navigating from any dynamic route then chunk loading failed error occurred again